# c# Read serial port weight cardinal scale 210

Tags: c#, parsing, serial-port

I've been able to show the data of the indicator to my computer,

the output look like-this

> "[SPACE][SPACE] 978 0Kg"

[SPACE] is space text (empty)

I want to display only numbers,

I use the following script.

```
private delegate void Closure();
    private void SerialPortOnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs serialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)     //<-- Makes sure the function is invoked to work properly in the UI-Thread
            BeginInvoke(new Closure(() => { SerialPortOnDataReceived(sender, serialDataReceivedEventArgs); }));     //<-- Function invokes itself
        else
        {
            while (_serialPort.BytesToRead > 0) //<-- repeats until the In-Buffer is empty
            {
                String tampung = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
                Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^\d|\.]");

                tampung = regex.Replace(tampung, "");


                textBox1.Text += string.Format("{0:X2} ", tampung);
            }
        }
    }
```

but it displays incomplete figures, the last number zero did not enter

output :

> 978

i'm using indicator http://www.cardinalscale.com/cs_product/210-storm/

Is there something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex to extract the numbers from the string, then `Trim` it to remove whitespaces.

```
string input = "  940 0Kg";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\d]", "").Trim();
```

And if you need it as a number, of course

```
int weight = int.Parse(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
String tampung = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^\d|\.]");
```

with

```
string tampung = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
string pattern = @"(\d+\.\,\d+)";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(tampung, pattern);
```